# How do i inject $transition$ to write jasmine test cases for component based routing to test resolve object?

Tags: angularjs, jasmine

I want to write test case for resolve object which has $transition$ as dependency. 
Here is my config:

```
angular.module("testing")
  .config(function($stateProvider) {
    $stateProvider.state({
      name: 'component.view',
      url: '/:componentName',      
      resolve: {
        componentName: ($transition$) => $transition$.params().componentName        
      }
    });
});
```

So i want to test the resolve object using jasmine. Please suggest me a work around . Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the solution. We can solve this by creating a provider. Here it is:

```
beforeEach(module('testing', function ($provide) {
    $provide.provider("$transition$", function () {
          this.$get = function () {           
            return {
                'params':function(){
                    return {
                        'componentName':'Component one'
                    };
                }
            };
          }
    })
}));
```